# Naming Google Benchmark values

Tags: c++, google-benchmark

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but, is there a way to name Google Benchmark argument values?

```
----------------               ----------
Benchmark                      Benchmark
----------------               ----------
NameTest/Alex      instead of  NameTest/0
NameTest/Bob                   NameTest/1
NameTest/Charles               NameTest/2
```

for a benchmark defined something like this:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto names = std::array{ "Alex", "Bob", "Charles" };

static void NameTest(benchmark::State& state)
{
    const auto name = names[state.range(0)];
}
BENCHMARK(NameTest)->DenseRange(0, names.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call `SetLabel` on the `State` object that is passed in.